# Firefox script problem

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, firefox

It is possible to start Firefox in Xubuntu 18.04 with the script below.
I've named the script `f` and if the argument `a` (`f a`) is used in the terminal, Firefox will open a new window on this address https://askubuntu.com/.
A short version looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Dette script er under udvikling til zutil på UbuntuDanmark.dk
# https://ubuntudanmark.dk/forum/viewtopic.php?p=141909#p141909
#
# Scriptet åbner adresser i Firefox, se -h for brug af argumenter.
# Ved indsættelse af et ekstra argument:
# Skab tom plads imellem to sekvenser med Enter.
# Find en passende sekvens, og kopier hele sekvensen ind på pladsen.
# Ret argument og kommando, og gem, og afprøv det nye argument i terminalen.


# Hovedsekvens begynd
case $1 in


# Sekvens begynd
    'a')
        firefox -new-window 'https://askubuntu.com/'
        ;;
# Sekvens slut
# Sekvens begynd
    'u')
        firefox -new-window 'https://ubuntudanmark.dk/forum/search.php?search_id=active_topics'
        ;;
# Sekvens slut
# Sekvens begynd
    'k')
        firefox -new-window 'https://www.klimadebat.dk/'
        ;;
# Sekvens slut
# Sekvens begynd
    'help'|'-h'|'-help'|'--help')
        clear
        echo "Anvendelse: - Åbner sider med Firefox."
        echo 'Syntaks: "['${0##*/}'] [Argument]"'
        echo ''
        echo 'Argumenter:'
        echo '  "-h"                  Viser denne hjælpe side'
        echo '  intet                 Åbner søgemaskine'
        echo '  ukendte               Åbner søgemaskine og søger på argumenter ( op til ni ord )'
        echo ''
        echo 'Andre argumenter:'
        echo ' a = ask ubuntu '
        echo ''
        echo ' k = danish climate debate'
        echo ''
        echo 'Eksempler:'
        echo '  "'${0##*/}' u"                 Åbner Ubuntu forum'
        echo '  "'${0##*/}' ukendte"           Åbner søgemaskine og søger på ordet "ukendte"'
        echo ''
        echo 'Kommandoen "ged '${0##*/}'" giver mulighed for at redigere '${0##*/}''
        ;;
# Sekvens slut
# Herunder kommandoen, som benyttes, når intet argument forinden er blevet genkendt.
    *)
        firefox -new-window 'https://www.google.com.au/#q='$1'+'$2'+'$3'+'$4'+'$5'+'$6'+'$7'+'$8'+'$9''
        ;;
# Herover kommandoen, som benyttes, når intet argument forinden er blevet genkendt.

esac
# Hovedsekvens slut.
```

The script has worked perfectly but after an update some weeks ago it will not always open the address correctly (page is blank).
Sometimes I have to do it two times or to be sure it works I can do it two times without first closing the first window.
I don't seem to be able to find a clear pattern in the way the error occurs.
Sometimes it works and sometimes it does not but if Firefox is already up running it works fine.

I do have faith in the script. As you can see it is developed in Denmark and has worked very fine for a long time.
Therefore I think it might have something to do with a minor mistake in Ubuntu update.

Can you help me find out what is wrong or perhaps you can help me find an option to force Firefox even harder to read the address and go to it?

---

Later:

I have now tried to use commands from the script directly in the terminal.
It seems to work at little better but also not without problems.
F.i. Firefox gave me message visiting this page:

```
firefox -new-window 'https://askubuntu.com/'
```

[Click here to see the picture from the visit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIFpL.png)

---

Later again:

If I use this command in the terminal:

```
firefox -new-window 'https://www.klimadebat.dk/' 'http://www.climate-debate.com/'
```

www.klimadebat.dk opens fine but the other window for www.climate-debate.com is blank.

Blank ( my startpage ) is the most common error and it looks like this (I expect no translation is needed for this):

[Blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svTAw.png)

If it is a network problem I don't know how to test it because everything else seems to work okay. Not the fastest but okay.

And sometimes when I use this command in the terminal prompt:

```
firefox -new-window 'https://askubuntu.com/'
```

I get this error:

[Page with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NB8zP.png)

I get the feeling it might have to do with the network not being fast enough or Firefox being too impatient or it fails to retry.

However when I do the same again and no error appears on the page I still might get a message like this in the terminal when I close Firefox:

> (/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:10431): dconf-WARNING **: 09:02:42.602:
>   Unable to open /var/lib/snapd/desktop/dconf/profile/user: Adgang
>   nægtet

( Adgang nægtet = Access denied )

I don't know if that can have anything to do with the problem since it comes along with no error on the page.

---

Later again again:

Maybe this clear pattern can help you to help me to find out what is wrong:

I turn on the computer and load Firefox and go on-line.
After that the script always works fine.

If I do the same and don't go on-line but I instead put this line in the script to do the job:

```
nmcli c up name_of_wifi_unit
```

It will not go on-line or it jumps off again immediately when Firefox opens.
It seems like Firefox is blocking the on-line procedure if it is up running. If Firefox is not up running the command works fine but then the original error comes back.

---

One day later:

**I recieved a large update today** and it has helped a lot.
Now the original problem is gone and the script works perfect as it used to. :-)

I think Firefox is still blocking "nmcli" but only if Firefox is up running before I run the script with nmcli and I usually never do that. I only did that to analyze the problem.

I am not finished testing. I just wanted to give you some response to my first experience with the last update to let you know it has a good effect.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please ***[edit]*** your question and show us the actual script. We can't help you with a script you don't show us.  Also, please explain exactly how it fails. Is the problem that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't?

Comment: [Your screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIFpL.png) shows the URL has been successfully passed to Firefox. The problem of the page not being displayed (“secure connection failed”) seems to be related to Firefox itself or your network configuration. You should also paste the error message as text into your question, so we could copy it to a translator, for example. Also consider switching Firefox to English when posting its messages to an English speaking site.